# How to write nginx rewrite to change filename to query

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm trying to write a rewrite rule to change said uri from example.com/download?name=room0003.php
to example.com/download?name=room.php&room=0003

I've tried:

```
rewrite ^download?name=room(....).php /download?name=room.php&room=$1;
```

I've also tried using if statements on $arg_name and $args but nothing has worked. The regex has been making my head hurt.

Comment: It would be better if you handle the query parameters through your `download.php` script. There is no need for rewriting unless you want to convert a pretty URL like `www.example.com/download/room/0003` to actually serve `/download/room.php?name=0003`